# HTML layout design - need better approach

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, resize

I have to design a layout for my project. There are arrangements of divs, upper Div, lower Div, fixed height, scrolling etc. It is difficult to describe the problem in words, hence I have attached an image below. Please refer the screenshots.

[image: HTML layout problem]

What I want to achieve is to arrange panels with respect to the overall height of the browser window. Pink module is absolute positioned at the bottom of the parent Div. Upper Div is precious sibling of pink Div and it contains panels. when browser is resized scrollbars should not appear in UpperDiv. Instead panels should show scroll (show in second).
It can be done using HTML and CSS and not at all I am hesistant using javascript or jquery. I appreciate any of your approach in doing this. Many thanks.

Sorry I couldn't made HTML properly. Currently my html shows scroll in upperDiv (instead scroll should appear in panels). Here I have created a fiddle. Please check.
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/NELBh/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: The HTML is explained in the pictures. If you could provide it, it would get you an answer quicker by saving everyone some time. Also, I love how the fixed height html changes height.

Comment: @Ash, clarify that fixed height thing.

Comment: Pink Div is fixed height because it contains certain buttons like next, previous and few others. Height approx. 270px :)

Answer (score 2):

Made some changes to the CSS, hope this is kinda what you are looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/vCVUL/embedded/result/

Regards.

Comment: I think this is close, but if you see the image the 'max height' for the panels is 'auto' or, conforming to their content. So the resizing there only needs to be done if the combined height of the panels is greater than the area of upperdiv. And he said something about an undefined amount of panels. (I was going to make what you have in your answer + this but since you're close anyway)

Comment: exactly, but we can manage even to change 33% to (25, 50, 20 etc.) by dividing the 100% by number of panels. close anyway. If **max-height:auto** in css worked, this problem would have solved, isn't it?

Comment: True, I think the only other way is within the `.resize` method you could possibly do some smart math to determine the children nodes and their height. its just frustrating that the answer to this isn't just some CSS and html. But someone is bound to get it right. going to have a look at it still though. regards.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ExtJS for this. Have look at the [demo](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/) page. There you find "Layout Managers" how will do the job for you.

Comment: ExtJS is a typical heavy js library, I wouldn't use it for a single application and write some custom JS with a lighter library, like jquery, for this specific layout where css is not sufficient.

Comment: You absolutly right, ExtJs is not for a single page application. I thought this project is bigger since the is doing a lot of planing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a much better way than, after page load, setting the dynamic section's height.
And to handle the resize, we can just bind the same function with JQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/N3HWz/7/

Comment: Thanks, but the problem of handling overflowing panels still exist. As you know I do not want to display scrolls for upperDiv.

Comment: Ah, I missed the part where you said you wanted to resize the window... answer updated.